# Load web page by getting html/css/js files from an user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have a zone for uploading files that allows the user to upload one HTML file and several JS and CSS files (only one page).

I want to use these files to create a webpage with the uploaded HTML, JS, and CSS which will be shown in an iframe. This will allow the user to add personalized content on my website. I can use Node.js for the server.

Comment: So what's the problem here? Why don't use `require` in Node.js to load file?

Comment: I didn't know that I could require a file of user. I thought only path can be require locally. And what about the including css and javascript in his html? It will be a confusion about path to display correctly the html in the iframe. Maybe doing a documentation of how path should be, can be a good idea.

Comment: It's not good idea use users file directly. Because may be user change or delete files later. Best solution in my idea is upload files to particular folders on your server then use their path by `require`

Comment: Normally, the user can close the iframe so it will deleted entirely his content. But it's a good idea I think i will develop your idea. Thanks a lot. Maybe I will ask some more questions here if I can't find answer to my future questions. :)